# How to set a mouse button combo as a hotkey?

Tags: button, mouse, autohotkey

Since I remapped XButton1 and XButton2 to ctrl+shift+tab and ctrl+tab
I wanted to set the right mouse button + XButton1/2 combos as forward&backward.

It works, but I don't have right click now...

I tried writing it as {RButton&XButton1}, needless to say that didn't help, but back/forward still works.

```
XButton1::Send ^+{Tab}
XButton2::Send ^{Tab}

RButton&XButton1::Send !{Left}
RButton&XButton2::Send !{Right}
```

I expect the right mouse button to work still as it is intended.

Answer (score 1):

The prefix key in a [custom combination](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#combo) (in this case RButton) loses its native function,

unless you add

```
RButton:: Send {RButton}
```

Comment: **Thanks that helped.** Found out about the ~ as well. 

I'm still learning about AutoHotkeys (discovered it today), didn't know that combo keys are called custom combination. :)

Comment: Just to add to my comment - putting a ~ in front of RButton was a better solution as the one suggested, because before I couldn't hold the right mouse button, it worked just as a right-click. With ~ it works perfectly.
```
~RButton & XButton1:: Send !{Left}
~RButton & XButton2:: Send !{Right}
```